# Polynomial roots related question

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

If a polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients has degree $d\ge 0$

Then prove that $P^2(x)-1$ can have atmost $(d+2)$ integer roots.

I am not able to solve this.

Basically I was trying to show that if $P(x)=1$ has $d$ distinct integer roots then $P(x)=-1$ can have maximum two distinct integer roots

Comment: You mean $\;P(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ (an integer polynomial), right?

Comment: All the coefficient of $P(x)$ are integers

Comment: Anyone with some hint or solution??????

Comment: $P^2(x)-1=(P(x)-1)(P(x)+1)$

Comment: Post a complete solution

Comment: I am not getting it....

Comment: Consider also that a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $d$ can have at most $d$ roots (i.e. at most $d$ solutions to $P(x)=0$ assuming $P(x)\neq0$). Now if you want to find how many solutions $P^2(x)-1=0$ can have, consider $(P(x)-1)(P(x)+1)=0$.

Comment: Still not getting it.....I have already tried this method.

Comment: No one with a solution yet...

Answer (score 1):

Above two statements are not equivalent. I mean, if you show the latter then the former is true but not conversely.